# How to get Date Of Birth parameters in my function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-design

**my view code is**

```
<div class="form-group {!! $errors->has('date_of_birth') ? 'has-error' : '' !!}">
{!! Form::label('date_of_birth', 'Date of Birth', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
<div class="form-inline">
{!! Form::selectRange('date_of_birth[day]', 1, 31, null, ['class' => 'selectbody fl']) !!}
{!! Form::selectMonth('date_of_birth[month]', null, ['class' => 'selectbody fl']) !!}
{!! Form::selectYear('date_of_birth[year]', date('Y') - 3, date('Y') - 40, null, ['class' => 'selectbody fl']) !!}
</div>
{!! $errors->first('date_of_birth', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>
```

**Here i am getting these parameters and i got DOB in array**

```
    public function signupme(Request $request)
    {
    $date_of_birth=$request->date_of_birth;
    print_r('$date_of_birth');
    }
```

**define column to save DOB**

```
    $data= array(
     "mybirthday"=>$date_of_birth,
    );
```

**saving in Database**

```
    if(DB::table('userspathik')->insert($data))
    {
    return redirect('signup')->with("success","You are registered");
    }
```

Comment: what is the question ? Where did you stuck ?

Comment: the code seems fine, what is your problem

Comment: @Hussein i want to ask the datetime is fine for storing date of birth?

Comment: @HasanTıngır how to get these parameters in my function..see the updated code.thank you

Comment: You should format your code first, I find missing closing bracket in your above code for schema function and missing form closing tag, I would suggest you start with the laravel docs, its more clear, concise and simple.

Comment: @Aryan please take a  look on code again .. the date of birth comes in array from view page and now i want to save that array values in mybirthday column

Answer (score 0):

You should be more clear with the question. So what I understand is that you have separate columns for day, month and year. When you submit the form you want these fields to be saved in a single 'datetime' column in the database.

I do not know what laravel version you're using but I expect it to be the latest one.

I would suggest you to use a single date input field and parse it with `strtotime` or `Carbon`, this way you would be able to validate it with laravel validation methods like `date, date_format, before, after` etc. Here's the sample:

```
public function signMeUp(Request $request)
{
    $validatedInput = $request->validate([
       'dob' => 'required|date|date_format:"d/m/Y"'
    ]);

    $dob = $validatedInput['dob'];

    # Parse the date according to format
    $dob = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dob);

    # Replace with your required model
    $model = new $model();
    $model->$dob;
    $model->save();

    return redirect('/register')->with('status', 'Registration Successful');

}
```

If you to use separate input fields like, day, month and year, you could just combine those fields, like

```
$dob = $request->get('dob_day').'/'.$request->get('dob_month').'/'.$request->get('dob_year');
```

you will need to validate it separately though.
You get the idea...